# In scala, why does the compiler doesn't explain the error message "diverging implicit expansion" even if '-Xlog-implicits' is used?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-compiler

I have a type class that has only 1 implementation:

```
class ConstDomain[N1, N2](
    val a1: Const[N1],
    val a2: Const[N2]
) {

  ...
}

object ConstDomain {

  implicit def summon[N1, N2](
      implicit
      a1: Const[N1],
      a2: Const[N2]
  ): ConstDomain[N1, N2] = new ConstDomain[N1, N2](a1, a2)
}
```

The function `summon` is then tested in a fairly simple case:

```
          val c1 = implicitly[Const[a.SS + b.SS]] // works properly
          val c2 = implicitly[Const[c.SS]] // works properly

          ConstDomain.summon[a.SS + b.SS, c.SS]
// throws the following error:
```

```
Op2Spec.scala:105: diverging implicit expansion for type edu.umontreal.kotlingrad.shapesafe.macro.arity.Proof.Const[a.SS + b.SS]
starting with value a
one error found
```

this error seems to indicate that there are multiple implicit implementations that can be summoned to fulfil parameter a1, but it doesn't tell where exactly these implementations are. So How should I query the compiler to explain it? My project is compiled using gradle kts, with option '-Xlog-implicits' already enabled and verified to be working:

```
    tasks {
        val jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()

        withType<ScalaCompile> {

            scalaCompileOptions.loggingLevel = "info"

            scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = arrayListOf(
                    "-encoding", "utf8",
                    "-unchecked",
                    "-deprecation",
                    "-feature",
                    "-Xfatal-warnings",
                    "-Xlog-implicits"
            )

            println(this.name)
            println(scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters)
        }
...
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *this error seems to indicate that there are multiple implicit implementations that can be summoned to fulfil parameter a1* I guess you misunderstand error "diverging implicit expansion". Existence of several suitable implicits is different error: "ambiguous implicit values". It's possible that "diverging implicit expansion" can be fixed with by-name implicits `=> ...` in 2.13 or with `shapeless.Lazy`/`Strict`.